# Rails routes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am following along with Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial 2nd Edition](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) and have reached the signin/signout section of the book.

So far I can create a new user (or in my case landlord) and log in with the new credentials. The problem I have is when signing out. I click "signout" and get a route error saying:

> No route matches [GET] "/signout"

Below are code snippets. Any help would be very appreciated!

rake routes output

```
landlords GET    /landlords(.:format)           landlords#index
               POST   /landlords(.:format)           landlords#create
  new_landlord GET    /landlords/new(.:format)       landlords#new
 edit_landlord GET    /landlords/:id/edit(.:format)  landlords#edit
      landlord GET    /landlords/:id(.:format)       landlords#show
               PUT    /landlords/:id(.:format)       landlords#update
               DELETE /landlords/:id(.:format)       landlords#destroy
    properties GET    /properties(.:format)          properties#index
               POST   /properties(.:format)          properties#create
  new_property GET    /properties/new(.:format)      properties#new
 edit_property GET    /properties/:id/edit(.:format) properties#edit
      property GET    /properties/:id(.:format)      properties#show
               PUT    /properties/:id(.:format)      properties#update
               DELETE /properties/:id(.:format)      properties#destroy
      sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)            sessions#create
   new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)        sessions#new
       session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)        sessions#destroy
          root        /                              content_pages#home
content_pages_home GET    /content_pages/home(.:format)  content_pages#home
          help        /help(.:format)                content_pages#help
     questions        /questions(.:format)           content_pages#questions
        signup        /signup(.:format)              landlords#new
        signin        /signin(.:format)              sessions#new
       signout DELETE /signout(.:format)             sessions#destroy
```

routes.rb file

```
  resources :landlords
  resources :properties
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root :to => 'content_pages#home'

  get "content_pages/home"

  match '/help', to: 'content_pages#help'
  match '/questions', to: 'content_pages#questions'
  match '/signup', to: 'landlords#new'
  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

link to signout

```
<%= link_to "Signout", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
```

sessions controller

```
def destroy
  sign_out
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: Do you have a `sign_out` method in the sessions helper? Look at listing 8.30 in the book/website. The `destroy` method of the controller is looking for it.

Comment: Yea I have a sign-out method in the session helper 'def sign_out
   self.current_landlord = nil
   cookies.delete(:remember_token)
 end'

Comment: Hey @TonyStaunton did the answer work for you? I am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `via:` option in the following code restricts the request to the delete method:

```
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

You'll need to make one that works with the 'get' method

Check out the [Rails Routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)